# update query based in values from the subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, subquery

```
declare @exampleTable table(
    id int,
    Quantity int
)

declare @exampleTable_Aux table(
    id int,
    Quantity int
)

insert into @exampleTable values(1,5),(2,8)
insert into @exampleTable_Aux values(1,3),(5,8)

select * from @exampleTable
select di_aux.id from @exampleTable di_aux inner join @exampleTable_Aux dij on di_aux.id=dij.id

declare @Quantity int;

UPDATE di SET Quantity=22
FROM @exampleTable di WHERE di.id in (select di_aux.id from @exampleTable di_aux inner join @exampleTable_Aux dij on di_aux.id=dij.id)
```

know if what I want is the Quantity to get the value from the subquery for example(invalid only to indicate what I pretend)

```
UPDATE di SET Quantity=@Quantity+di.Quantity
FROM @exampleTable di WHERE di.id in (select di_aux.id,@Quantity=dij.Quantity from @exampleTable di_aux inner join @exampleTable_Aux dij on di_aux.id=dij.id)
```

should get the table:
How can i do that if its even possible to update the query base in the values from the subquery?

```
  id Quantity
1 1  8
2 2  8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `sub-query` at all. Just `Update` the table `@exampleTable` by joining `@exampleTable_Aux`

Here is the correct way

```
UPDATE di_aux
SET    di_aux.Quantity = dij.Quantity + di_aux.Quantity
FROM   @exampleTable di_aux
       INNER JOIN @exampleTable_Aux dij
               ON di_aux.id = dij.id
```

Comment: sorry my example wasn't good, because in case that I am working if I do the inner join the row that I want to update will not be in the table returned from inner join that is why I was using the subquery, nvm you are right just need to change the condition of the ON